# Why is android studio downloading components again?

Tags: android-studio, admin-rights

I changed my account from admin to other. why is android studio downloading components again. I downloaded everything previously... How to proceed?

Comment: What components? What is "everything"? What do you mean proceed; is AS not working correctly now?

Comment: i dont want to download every thing again... that is sdks and avds again...

Comment: The SDK components can be moved. Usually the settings and the gradle distributions file are in /home/user/... folders.

Comment: you mean move it to the other user? do i have to move the avds too? can't i just point to the previous location?

Comment: About the sdk. It is just a folder. You can move this folder in other location and set it on Android Studio config.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly used the default location for android sdk. You can move it, while the studio is turned off. The next time you start it, it will ask you to tell him where the new location is.
Also gradle wrapper downloads some other files, like gradle itsels. That is also stored for each user, but don't worry about this